# No programs can't be downloaded / installed with terminal

Tags: downloads

I get this error all the time I want to install something in terminal, it started with deluge then I saw more and more programs would not install or download

```
$ sudo apt-get install firefox
Reader package list ... Done
Creates an overview of addictive relationships
Reading status information ... Done
You already have the latest version of firefox (57.0.1 + build2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1).
You may want to perform "apt-get -f install" to correct these:
The following packages have unrelated addictions:
 linux-image-extra-4.10.0-42-generic: Depends on: linux-image-4.10.0-42-generic but not installed
 linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04: Depends on: linux-image-4.10.0-42-generic but not installed
E: Unrestricted addiction. Try "apt-get -f install" without packages (or set a solution).
```

Yes I've tried with `apt-get -f install`, not working.

```
$ uname -r
4.10.0-40-generic

$ dpkg -l | grep linux-image
ii  linux-image-4.10.0-38-generic               4.10.0-38.42~16.04.1                                         amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.10.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.10.0-40-generic               4.10.0-40.44~16.04.1                                         amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.10.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.10.0-38-generic         4.10.0-38.42~16.04.1                                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.10.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.10.0-40-generic         4.10.0-40.44~16.04.1                                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.10.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
iU  linux-image-extra-4.10.0-42-generic         4.10.0-42.46~16.04.1                                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.10.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
iU  linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04               4.10.0.42.44                                                 amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
```

Comment: what is name of your os and the version of it?

Comment: I am almost sure that the phrases *"addictive relationships"*, *"unrelated addictions"* and *"unrestricted addiction"* are not in the vocabulary of `apt-get`. If those phrases actually appear when you run `apt-get` then something is profoundly wrong with your system.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the complete output of `uname -r` and `dpkg -l | grep linux-image`

Comment: i have xubuntu, when i typed apt-get i got this:  kristoffer@HP-Stream-Laptop-14-ax0XX:~$ I am almost sure that the phrases "addictive relationships", "unrelated addictions" and "unrestricted addiction" are not in the vocabulary of apt-get. If those phrases actually appear when you run apt-get then something is profoundly wrong with your system. –

Comment: I suggest that you don't use google translate on error messages. It may be slightly confusing.

Comment: @vidarlo I don't think google translate is involved here. I rather think of two possibilities: either the OP re-typed the message instead of cut'n'pasting it (and was a bit sloppy) OR the system is really, really messed up.

Comment: @PerlDuck I believe google translate is involved. In norwegian dependency is avhengighet, which is *usually* translated as addictive - and also by Google Translate :)

Comment: @vidarlo Ah, ok. Wasn't aware of that. I'm German and we suffer from strange translations (in both directions) as well. Sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 0):

use this command to open your source list:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

in the opened file, uncomment (remove #) main, universe and multivers repository links. lines should be something like this (in `xubuntu 16.04` for example):

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main universe 
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main universe multiverse
```

after that, save the file. in terminal run the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
```

then try to install firefox or anything else.

Comment: your deb commands does not exaclly match like mne. can i just delete the simiilars? like::: xenial universe, xenial-updates universe, xenial-updates universe

Comment: no, do not delete them, find the similar ones and uncomment them by removing the '#' sign

Comment: i dont think i cam find them,when i search for the words with CTRL+F gives not any resulates eighter....

Comment: i updated my answer, add those lines to your source.list

Comment: i added the two lines at the buttom ran update, after i tried to install deluge and i get the same error

Comment: for deluge you must add a custom ppa using:
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deluge-team/ppa`
`sudo apt update && sudo apt install deluge`